# How to implement scrolling in TableLayout?

Tags: android

I have implemented simple database android application.In which I have displayed list of name and images.But if data is more then ten then table layout is not scrolling vertically.

Is it possible to implement vertical scrolling without using scrollview?
If possible then please provide me some reference.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is a link [link](http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/01/android/android-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/) . It contains a example, but that for layout there is used **LinearLayout**. you just need to write comment over there that i want in **TableLayout**. so that by using in response, i will past code in TableLayout.

Answer (score 5):

Why do you want to do it without using ScrollView? You can simply wrap your TableLayout inside a ScrollView to add the functionality.

I've always used ScrollView so I can't really give you a way to do this without using it.

Random link off Google that explains it pretty well: http://huuah.com/using-tablelayout-on-android/

Answer (score 1):

As @Klaus said, you have to implement a ScrollView. Nonetheless, you can set

```
android:scrollbars="@null"
```

in the XML resource and in that way the scrollbar will be "invisible"

Answer (score 0):

Hi
Here is a good article http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/01/android/android-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/. It is in LinearLayout but is someone write comment over there then i can convert the layout file into TableLayout.